# Secure AWS s3 uploads to premium users only?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to build an application that has a "premium" feature to upload files to s3.

Right now the users login using OAuth/Cognito.  There is a dynamoDB table that contains user data based off their cognito id.  That dynamodb user data specifies if the user is a premium user or not.

I have an API gateway endpoint tied to a lambda function that creates the pre-signed s3 upload url.

How do I ensure the individual who calls API gateway is logged in and is a premium user before I return the pre-signed url?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [Lambda custom authorizer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) that verifies the user is a "premium" user before authorizing the request to the API gateway endpoint. This function would lookup the user in DynamoDB before authorizing access.

Comment: What I'm currently confused about:  once authenticated with cognito, is the session token the same token as the "authorization token" that's described in the documentation from the url you provided?

Comment: If I use a Custom Authorizer, then I loose the AWS Cognito auth enforcement (and I have to build that out myself as part of the Custom Authorizer).  I'd prefer to not have to do that if possible.  Can you see any other way around it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Cognito Federated Identities, you can access the Cognito Identity Id from your Lambda function behind API gateway, and do the lookup in your dynamo table.

In order to access the Cognito Identity Id, you must have "Invoke with caller credentials" on the API Gateway "Integration Request" page of the API.

Once this is set, and you are calling your API using the credentials from Cognito, the lambda context will have a new "identity" struct, containing the "cognitoIdentityId" and the "cognitoIdentityPoolId"

Comment: I don't think it's possible to enable "Invoke with caller credentials" when I'm using a Custom Authorizer.  Would you suggest I drop the custom authorizer and just use AWS's authorizer and then do the "premium" lookup at the beginning of each lambda call?  (That's essentially what the custom authorizer does, just it caches the results too).